# testing of composite null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, inference

Is the following result true?

If $ϕ_0$ is a most powerful $\alpha$-level test for testing $H_0\!\!: \theta = \theta_0$ against $H_1\!\!: \theta = \theta_1$, then $\phi_0$ is a most powerful test for testing $H_0\!\!: \theta \in \Omega_0$ against $H_1\!\!: \theta = \theta_1$, provided $\sup_{\theta\ \in\ \Omega_0} E_\theta(\phi_0)\le \alpha$ is satisfied where $\theta_0\in \Omega_0$.

(Here $\Omega_0$ is a subspace of the parameter space, and we want to test for the parameter $\theta$. $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are points in the parameter space, and $E$ denotes the expectation.

If yes, then for testing $\mathcal N(\theta, 1)$, $H_0\!\!: \theta\le 5$ against $H_1\!\!: \theta=7$, why is the most powerful test obtained for the simple vs simple test $H_0\!\!: \theta=4$ against $H_1\!\!: \theta=7$ is not most powerful for the composite vs simple test?